# Is it possible to attach volume and elastic IP automatically to Spot ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I would like to try to setup AWS Launch Template, or just Spot request (persistance) and I need automatically attach my specific volume.

The main idea - spot instance will be process data and store it in a separate volume. When Spot will die, another Spot should be requested automatically (which will be built from an image with predefined software) and data should continue processing automatically (and again, storing in my second volume).

But, I can`t setup it in AWS console, so, looks like it is not possible. Am I wrong? Is it possible in some another way?

The same according IP address - I would like to have the same IP address for any of "versions" of Spot (after recreating for example)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to attach and detach Elastic IP using AWS CLI to achieve what you want.

However there are other possible workarounds in case you do not want to script AWS CLI :

1. Using Route53 you can define an A record with TTL of 60 seconds if you can accept few minutes of transition. That way you get to use a domain to access your underlying instance instead.
2. Setup a ALB and forward the request to the EC2 fleet